# getting error while implementing headers, body in Scrapy Spider

Tags: scrapy

When trying to scrap a page passing headers and body i get the following error show below.

i tried converting to json, str and sending it but it doesn't give any results.
please let me know if anything needs to be changed..

**Code**

```
import scrapy

class TestingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"

    def start_requests(self):

        request_headers = {
           "Host": "host_here",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 20100101 Firefox/46.0",
           "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
           "Connection": "keep-alive",
           "Cache-Control": "max-age=0"
        }

        url = "my_url_here"

        payload = {
            "searchargs.approvedFrom.input": "05/18/2017",
            "searchargs.approvedTO.input": "05/18/2017"
            "pagesize": -1
        }

        yield scrapy.Request(url, method="POST", callback=self.parse, headers=request_headers, body=payload)


    def parse(self, response):
        print("-------------------------------came here-------------------------------")
        print(response.body)
```

**Error 1**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/suventure/home/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/home/suventure/Desktop/suventure-projects/python-projects/scraper_txrrc/scraper_txrrc/spiders/wells_spider.py", line 114, in start_requests
    yield scrapy.Request(url, method="POST", callback=self.parse, headers=request_headers, body=payload)
  File "/home/suventure/home/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 26, in __init__
    self._set_body(body)
  File "/home/suventure/home/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 68, in _set_body
    self._body = to_bytes(body, self.encoding)
  File "/home/suventure/home/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 117, in to_bytes
    'object, got %s' % type(text).__name__)
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got dict
```

**Error 2 without any response if dict is converted to string and sent in body**

```
2017-05-19 22:39:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: scraper_)
2017-05-19 22:39:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'scraper', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scraper_.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scraper_.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True}
2017-05-19 22:39:39 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2017-05-19 22:39:39 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-05-19 22:39:39 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-05-19 22:39:39 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline']
2017-05-19 22:39:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-05-19 22:39:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-05-19 22:39:39 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-05-19 22:39:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://website_link_here/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-05-19 22:39:40 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <POST website_link_here>
2017-05-19 22:39:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-05-19 22:39:40 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 232,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 258,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 19, 17, 9, 40, 581949),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 19, 17, 9, 39, 332675)}
2017-05-19 22:39:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: The error messages tell you that the body parameter is a dict (your payload) but it should be a unicode or str. Scrapy documentation of Request tells the same. So you need to convert your dict to unicode like `request_body = json.dumps(payload)`

Comment: @FrankMartin i have already tried with this kind of code since it was mentioned in stackoverflow,  with this code callback which is shown doesn't get called and no error

Comment: Can you add the output of your `scrapy crawl test` command to your question?

Comment: i have given information about the error in the post

Comment: There is a message `DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt`. Habe a look at the setting `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY`

Comment: it gives results but what exactly it does

Comment: It's written in the documentation:  https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey .

Comment: i have multiple spider files can i enable/disable only for specific files

Comment: Yes - as a setting per spider which is described on the same documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings.py change

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Comment: it gives results but what exactly it does

Comment: If ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False then scrapy ignore disallow section in robots.txt